# Update HTML page on submit button with flask and python

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-wtforms

What I'm trying to achieve:
I'm creating this small web app that will connect to given ip/s over telnet, send some commands, get back some responses and display them in the html page.
Everything I mentioned above will take place on the same page.
Most of the stuff is working.

Problem:
I'm trying to display the response/s I get back from those ip/s, in the same HTML page I submit the telnet command from, in a `textarea` upon pressing the `submit` button.
The responses are sent back to the html_template in a form of a list `player_responses`.
What happens right now is that my loop creates a new `textarea` for each element in the response list, not cool.
![current behavior]https://imgur.com/a/4PCNEjs
I just want to update the already existing `textarea` with all the responses.
This happens in `<div id="console">` in my `player-poll.html`

Disclaimer:
I'm a noob, don't know what I'm doing most of the time.

To my defence I looked through the suggested posts and did some research on my own, however did not find an answer to my dilemma.

app.py

```py
@app.route('/player-poll', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def player_poll():
    form = PlayerPollForm()
    player_responses = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for i in form.ip_addr.data.split():
            player_responses.append(f'Response from {i} is TELNET_ RESPONSE')
            print(f'Item fount {i}')
        print(player_responses)
    return render_template('player-poll.html', title='Player Poll', form=form, len_player_responses=len(player_responses), player_responses=player_responses)
```

forms.py

```py
class PlayerPollForm(FlaskForm):
    ip_addr = TextAreaField('Players IP address one per line:', validators=[DataRequired()])
    cmd = StringField('Command:', validators=[DataRequired()])
    freq = FloatField('Frequency in sec:', validators=[DataRequired()])
    count = IntegerField('Number of Iterations:', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Send Command')
    logs = TextAreaField('Player Logs:')
```

player-poll.html

```html
{% extends "template_layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form action="{{ url_for('player_poll') }}" method="POST">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Player Poll</legend>
                    <div id="row-1" class="row">
                        <div id="col-1" class="col">
                            {{ form.ip_addr.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="row-2" class="row">
                        <div id="col-1" class="col">
                            {{ form.ip_addr(class="form-control", rows="10", placeholder="Type your player ip addresses here, one per line.") }}
                        </div>
                        <div id="col-2" class="col">
                            <div id="row-2-6" class="row" style="padding-right: 15px">
                                <div class="col-sm-8 text-left" style="padding-left: 0">
                                    {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-primary btn-lg") }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="console" class="row" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px">
                        <legend class="border-bottom mb-2">Player Poll Logs:</legend>
                        <textarea id=playerPollLog class="form-control form-group" rows=17">Responses</textarea>
                        {% if request.method == 'POST' %}
                            {% for i in range(0, len_player_responses) %}
                                <textarea id=playerPollLog class="form-control form-group" rows=17">{{ player_responses[i] }}</textarea>
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: you use `for`-loop which creates many `textarea`- why ? If you want only one `textarea` then don't create them in loop but put all text in existing `textarea` - use `for`-loop inside `<textarea>`. OR concatenate all text in `view.py` and send only one string to template and add to `<textarea>` without `for`-loop.

Comment: Good idea to use `for` loop inside my `textarea`, did not cross my mind to do that.  As I said, I'm kinda new to flask and html not my thing. Thanks, that helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand - but if you want only one textarea then don't create them in `for`-loop but use `for`-loop inside existing `<textarea>`

```
   <textarea id=playerPollLog class="form-control form-group" rows="17">Responses
        {% for response in player_responses %}
            {{ response }}
        {% endfor %}
   </textarea>
```

---

Eventually you could concatenate all responses in `app.py` and send it to tempalte as single string - ie. `player_all_responses`.

```
   <textarea id=playerPollLog class="form-control form-group" rows="17">Responses
        {{ player_all_responses }}
   </textarea>
```